# Need to create vnet with two subnet in azure using java sdk (Java code, IntelliJ, gradle/maven)

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, sdk, azure-sdk, azure-java-sdk

create vnet and two subnet in azure using java sdk.

IntelliJ development setup with environment variable setup.

Share the git repository url

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/network?view=azure-java-stable):

Maven `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-network</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example of virtual network with two subnets:

```
Network network = azure.networks().define("mynetwork")
    .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
    .withNewResourceGroup()
    .withAddressSpace("10.0.0.0/28")
    .withSubnet("subnet1", "10.0.0.0/29")
    .withSubnet("subnet2", "10.0.0.8/29")
    .create();
```

For more examples, you can refer to [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java)